# Send image file between Android and iPhone by bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I need a your help

I'm making a file transfer app By Bluetooth and Wifi

But i can't find how send files from Android to iPhone by bluetooth

1 ) How send files from Android to iPhone ??

2 ) Where is sample codes ?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS there are currently two ways to send/receive files over Bluetooth. The first way is over Bluetooth Classic which uses the External Accessory Framework. This does however require that the device you are connected to is MFi enabled, which (to the best of my knowledge) no Android-phone is. The other way is over BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) which uses the Core Bluetooth Framework. BLE is designed to be very low power and thus have a pretty low throughput. It is possible to send larger files (like images) over it though, but you will probably have to cut the image in smaller pieces and stitch the data back together on the receiver side. You can read about the framework in the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetooth_concepts.pdf