# Cross platform chat between android-iphone using bluetooth

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth

I m stuck at a code where I have to implement chat between android-iphone using bluetooth. I did R & D and find some links that said we can't 
here is a link:

---

[**link 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723899/send-image-file-between-android-and-iphone-by-bluetooth)

[link 2](http://blog.moritzhaarmann.de/blog/2014/04/27/sorry-state-of-p2p/)

[link 3](http://www.quora.com/What-is-an-example-of-a-bluetooth-app-across-both-iPhone-and-Android)

[link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008507/android-4-3-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral/18020153#18020153)

[link 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth)

How can I do this?

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410081/communicating-between-ios-and-android-with-bluetooth-le

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer data between iOS and Android via Bluetooth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884705/transfer-data-between-ios-and-android-via-bluetooth)

Comment: it may be possible , i think this is the certification case of bluetooth that's why iphone do not permitted to visible its device in other android phones ... but i need to know about other possible scenario where i can chat with iphone via bluetooth with third party access . how it can possible or possible or not ???